# Memory leak with Chromium Embedded interop ActiveX control using CEFSharp WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, vb6, com-interop, chromium

A while ago I posted [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522735/cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-in-interop-user-control) about creating a COM Interop wrapper for the CEFSharp WPF form as an alternative to the Internet Explorer ActiveX control. We ended up not needing to use it, at the time, but it's starting to look like we will need to again. In any case, since I last posted I've successfully gotten everything working and created an install packaging for the web control -- sadly, it appears to have a memory leak. The good news is that I think I know what is happening, the bad news, however, is that nothing I have tried seems to fix it.

The project has a single class, **WebControl**, which inherits **System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost** and has a private variable for the **CEFSharp.WPF.WebView**. The class includes all of the VB6 Interop code from the Interop Forms Toolkit (all of the COM registration, properties, events, and methods). It also has a public Navigate method that calls the appropriate CEFSharp Load method.

So, here's the fun part: The class constructor for the control initializes the **CEFSharp.WPF.WebView**. This means that the WebView is instantiated in VB6 at **design time** -- when the control is added to the parent form -- rather than at run time -- when the form is loaded or shown. Worse, I can set up a WndProc method to handle **WM_DESTROY** and shut down the hosted WPF element, but **WM_DESTROY** gets called when you close the designer or when you unload the form, which means when you re-load the parent form, the underlying **CEFSharp.Wpf.WebView** no longer exists. The crux of the issue seems to be that I do not have a way to initialize the control when the form loads, because the form is part of the VB6 project that is consuming the control; unless you dynamically add the control at run time in VB6 rather than using the designer, I suppose.

Anyway, if anyone has any questions or thoughts on how to approach this differently, I'd love to hear it. I'm considering posting the project as an open source alternative COM ActiveX Control, but I'm not sure how niche the interest would be -- technologically, it seems to be going in the wrong direction.

Comment: In `VB6` one has `UserControl_Init/ReadProperties` events on the base class that can be used to dynamicly create constituent controls. In your case the container (Excel, VB6 forms) will try to use first `IPersistPropertyBag` on the control then other `IPersistXxx` interfaces to load design-time properties -- hook these for startup initialization!

Comment: @Karter how did you get on with this issue? I need an ActiveX web browser control and I'm thinking of emulating what you've done with CEFSharp, but I'm not sure I have the know-how to tackle any really thorny COM problems. On balance was it worth the pain?