# How can I create an Active X control to use Chromium Embedded Framework to replace the WebBrowser control in Powerbuilder 12 classic?

Tags: activex, com-interop, powerbuilder, chromium-embedded

I need to be able to use the modern CSS3 and javascript support of Chrome in a powerbuilder classic 12 project.

I found this post [Memory leak with Chromium Embedded interop ActiveX control using CEFSharp WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455456/memory-leak-with-chromium-embedded-interop-activex-control-using-cefsharp-wpf)

where it seems that a member has successfully created an interop activex control. This is what I need to do and I need some help doing so.

Comment: So you want someone else to do the work for you?

Comment: Man - answer for you question will be as Matt say - just do it.
Someone from ceforum already do it, or do some similar.
But anyone did not say for you how to solve this task step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to USE the interop ActiveX control like mentioned in the post you included than simply use it the same way the other person did. Find out where they got the interop control and use it like normal in PB.

I think that you are wanting to develop an ActiveX wrapper which will then be used in PB. As the name implies (wrapper) just create an ActiveX project in Visual Studio and start mapping the properties/events/functions until your wrapper is complete. If you didn't know the basic steps for creating a wrapper than it shouldn't take more than ten minutes on the internet to get an idea of what that is and how to do it.

Also to help you out being a new StackOverflow member, I'd suggest using better tags for the best results. I see why you chose a few of them but 3 of 4 have fewer than 100 followers so your question is not being seen much at all (thank goodness for you on this one). I'd have put this under .NET, C# for top exposure and maybe keep the chromium tag which will help people searching for the answer down the road, it isn't helping you find the answer with less than 100 followers.

Oh, if you need someone to write the wrapper- I am looking for work and can do it for few hours/days pay depending on how much you need exposed.